# problem with getting next page data using api flutter

Tags: flutter

hey guys i got a small problem .

i made a program that shows some films from api , but the api has pages
so i made a scroll controller and all things work fine .

but when i reach the end of the list and the program loads more it travelles me to the start of the page.

i tried to use the infinite scroll pagination package but there is no videos explaining it so i couldnt use it .
this is my code .

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:MyCima/models/films_data_model.dart';
import 'package:MyCima/services/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../constants.dart';
import 'films_card.dart';

class ShowsListDesign extends StatefulWidget {

  final String filterName;
  const ShowsListDesign(this.filterName, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowsListDesignState createState() => _ShowsListDesignState();
}

class _ShowsListDesignState extends State<ShowsListDesign> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ServicesClass service = ServicesClass();
  FilmsDataModel modelClass = FilmsDataModel();
  late Future<List> filmsFutureList;
  int pageNumber = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(pageNumber == 1) {
      filmsFutureList = getFilmsList();
    }
    controller.addListener(listenScrolling);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(listenScrolling);
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List> getFilmsList()async {

    return await service.getFilms('posts/$pageNumber/${widget.filterName}') ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: filmsFutureList,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 24,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 24,
                      childAspectRatio: (2 / 3),
                    ),
                    controller: controller,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      modelClass =
                          FilmsDataModel.fromJson(snapshot.data[index]);
                      return FilmsCard(
                        image: modelClass.thumbUrl,
                        title: modelClass.title,
                        year: modelClass.year,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      scrollUp();
                    },
                    elevation: 24,
                    backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Scroll Up',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No Connection'),
              );
          }
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  void scrollUp() {
    const double start = 0;
    controller.animateTo(start,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 50),
        curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  void listenScrolling() {
    if (controller.position.atEdge) {
      final isTop = controller.position.pixels == 0;
      if (isTop) {
        //refresh method
      } else {
        getNxtPageData();
      }
    }
  }

   Future<void> getNxtPageData() async{
    pageNumber++;

    filmsFutureList = getFilmsList();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `setState((){})` and it rebuilds the widget, it takes back it to the top of the screen. You should add `ValueKey` with your `FilmsCard()`. Please keep in mind that `ValueKey` must be unique.

```dart
                  GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 24,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 24,
                      childAspectRatio: (2 / 3),
                    ),
                    controller: controller,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      modelClass =
                          FilmsDataModel.fromJson(snapshot.data[index]);
                      return FilmsCard(
                        key: Valuekey(modelClass.id), // Add ValueKey
                        image: modelClass.thumbUrl,
                        title: modelClass.title,
                        year: modelClass.year,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: i was thinking about this problem day and night till i found the the circular progress indicator is the problem coz it takes all the screen then when it disappears it returns to the top , when i deleted the indicator it worked normally but that gave me another problem that i cant make an indicator

Comment: You can use this package for pagination, it will help you out in every situation. [https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Comment: do u have a video for someone explaining how to use it ?